# Can I edit MySQL query by adding conditional parameter using Nodejs

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js

I am trying to create response json for a query where it gives me publication statistics by year. But i also want to get publication not by year. How can I achieve that? Below is the example my code:

```
let query = 'SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE program_id=?';
let params = [scrubbed_values.programid];

if (year !== undefined) {
  query += ' AND `year_published`=?';
  params.push(year);
}
```

Is it possible to write like this?
Thank you for answer.

Comment: this should work, what problem are you having?

Comment: Why do you think this wouldn't work? MySQL doesn't know or care how the SQL string is constructed. It's the same whether you create it all at once or by concatenating incrementally. The same with the `params` array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It behaves weird when I try to concatenate. When I dont put year parameter, it doesnt show any result but when I put year, it shows total result not for that particular year. That means it is behaving opposite of what I want.

Comment: Are you sure the `if` condition is true? Add a `console.log()` call into the `if` block to ensure the condition is correct.

Comment: Right now, i am getting an error "ER_parse_error: you have an error in your SQL syntax" check the manual that corresponds to your Mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near '!year_published='2018''...and this made me think that sql may have problem with concatenating.

Comment: Where is that `!` coming from? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: And the code has backticks which aren't in the error message. I don't think you posted the actual code.